# I have run the following program in netbeans, the build was successful but when I run the java file I get the following exception:

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I have run the following Graph.java code in Netbeans, the build was successful but when I run the java file individually to create the applet then the following exception appears:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
        at project.Graph.init(Graph.java:586)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)
```

Graph.java

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
class Node {
    double x;
    double y;
    int lane;
    int road;
    double dx;
    double dy;
    String lbl;
    int carW;
    int carL;
    double carWaiting;
}

class ChangeLight implements Runnable {
    int signal;
    int pauss, redpauss, greenpauss;
    Thread lighter;

    ChangeLight(){
       signal=1;
       redpauss=6000;
       greenpauss=6000;
   }

public void run() {
              signal=1;
    while (true) {
        if (signal==1){
                      signal=0;
                      pauss=greenpauss;
                  }
                  else {
                      signal=1;
                      pauss=redpauss;
                  }
        try {
        Thread.sleep(pauss);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
        }
    }
    }
    public void start() {
    lighter = new Thread(this);
    lighter.start();
    }
    public void stop() {
    lighter.stop();
    }
}  

class CalFlow implements Runnable {
    int carnum, count;
    double carwt;
    int pauss;
    double time0, time1, timelap;
    double carflow[] = new double[40];

    Thread flow;

    CalFlow(){
      carnum=0;
      carwt=0;
      pauss=2000;
      time0=0;
      time1=0;
      for (int k=0; k<40; k++)
         carflow[k]=0;
      count=0;
   }

    public void run() { 
    while (true) {  
                 time1= System.currentTimeMillis();
                 timelap=time1-time0;
                 if (timelap >50) 
         carflow[count]= ((double)(carnum)/timelap)*1000; 
                 count=(count+1)%40;

        try {
        Thread.sleep(pauss);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
        }
    }
    }
    public void start() {
    flow = new Thread(this);
    flow.start();
    }
    public void stop() {
    flow.stop();
    }
}  


class GraphPanel extends Applet implements Runnable {
    Graph graph;
    int nnodes;
    int lghtOrStp;
    Node nodes[] = new Node[100];
    ChangeLight  light[] = new ChangeLight[5];
    CalFlow carpermin[] = new CalFlow[5];
    Thread relaxer, flow;
    int brgflag[] = new int[5];
    double speed=10;
    int carwidth=6, carlength=9;
    int xpos[]= new int[5];
    int ypos=200;
    int brgright[] = new int[5];
    int brgleft[] = new int[5]; 
    int brgtop =ypos+ carlength; 
    int brgbottom=ypos- carlength;
    int rdleft[]=new int[5];
    int rdright[] = new int[5];
    int rdtop= ypos+ carwidth, rdbottom= ypos- carwidth;

    GraphPanel(Graph graph) {


              lghtOrStp=1;                                    //stop :0, light: 1
    this.graph = graph;
              for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
              {
               light[i]= new ChangeLight();
               carpermin[i]= new CalFlow();

               xpos[i]=150*(i+1);
               brgright[i]=xpos[i]- carlength;
               brgleft[i]=xpos[i]+ carlength;
               brgflag[i]=0;
                }
               for(int k=1; k<4; k++){
                  rdleft[k]= xpos[k-1]- carwidth;
                  rdright[k]= xpos[k-1]+ carwidth; 
               }
              rdleft[0]=0;
              rdright[0]=0;
      }

    int findNode(String lbl) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nnodes ; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].lbl.equals(lbl)) {
        return i;
        }
    }
    return addNode(lbl);
    }
    int addNode(String lbl) {
               int temp;
     Node n = new Node();
               temp = (int)(5*Math.random());
               if (temp==0||temp==4){
                     n.x = 480 + 210*Math.random();
                     n.y= ypos;
                     n.carW=carlength;
                     n.carL=carwidth;
                }
               else{
                     n.x= xpos[temp-1];
                     n.y= 10+100*Math.random();
                     n.carW=carwidth;
                     n.carL=carlength;
                }
//              temp=(int)(3*Math.random());                   // three lanes
//      n.y = 150+50*temp;
               if (temp==4)
                   temp=0;
               n.road=temp;
     n.lbl = lbl;
               n.carWaiting=-1;
     nodes[nnodes] = n;
     return nnodes++;
    }

public void run() {
              for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
                  light[j].signal=1;

              flow = new Thread(carpermin[0]);   
              carpermin[0].time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
              carpermin[0].carnum=0;
              flow.start();
    while (true) {
        relax();
        try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
        }
    }
    }

    synchronized void relax() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nnodes; i++) {  
                  if (nodes[i].road==0){
                    nodes[i].dx = -speed*Math.random();
          nodes[i].dy = 2*Math.random()-1;
                   }
                  else{
                    nodes[i].dy = speed*Math.random();
          nodes[i].dx = 2*Math.random()-1;
                  }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nnodes ; i++) {
        Node n1 = nodes[i];
        double dx = 0;
        double dy = 0;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nnodes ; j++) {
                            Node n2 = nodes[j];
        if (i == j||n1.road!=n2.road) {
            continue;
        }
                            double vx;
        if(n1.road==0)
            vx = n1.x - n2.x;
                            else
                                vx= n2.y-n1.y;
                            if (vx<0)
                                 continue;
                            double len=vx;

                            if( len<(n2.carW+n2.carL)){
                                if (n1.carWaiting<0) 
                                  n1.carWaiting= System.currentTimeMillis();

                                 if(n1.road==0)
                                      n1.dx=0;
                                 else
                                      n1.dy=0;
                              }                                 
        }

    }         
//move a car
     Dimension d = size();
               double temp;
                 for (int i = 0 ; i < nnodes ; i++) {
            Node n = nodes[i];
                       if(n.road==0){ 
                          temp=n.x;
                n.x += Math.max(-10, Math.min(10, n.dx));
                          for (int k=0; k<3; k++){
                              if ((n.x<brgleft[k]&&n.x>brgright[k])&&brgflag[k]==1){  
                                if(temp> brgleft[k] ||temp<brgright[k])
                                    n.x=temp;
                              }
                             else if ((n.x< brgleft[k] &&n.x>brgright[k])&&brgflag[k]==0)
                                if (lghtOrStp==0)
                                    brgflag[k]=1;
                                else{
                                    if (light[k].signal==0)
                                        brgflag[k]=1;
                                    else
                                        n.x=temp;
                                }
                             else if(temp< brgleft[k] &&temp>brgright[k])
                                 brgflag[k]=0;
        if (n.x < 0) {
            n.x = d.width-10*Math.random();
                                carpermin[0].carnum=carpermin[0].carnum+1;
        } else if (n.x > d.width) {
            n.x = d.width-10*Math.random();
        }
                             if (n.x!=temp&&n.carWaiting==-1){
                                   carpermin[0].carwt+= System.currentTimeMillis()-
n.carWaiting;
                                   n.carWaiting=-1;
                             }
                            }
                      }
                    else{
                          temp=n.y;
                n.y += Math.max(-10, Math.min(10, n.dy));
                          if ((n.y<brgtop&&n.y>brgbottom)&&brgflag[n.road-1]==1){  
                             if(temp> brgtop ||temp<brgbottom)
                                n.y=temp;     
                           }
                          else if ((n.y< brgtop &&n.y>brgbottom)&&brgflag[n.road-1]==0)
                                    if (lghtOrStp==0)
                                         brgflag[n.road-1]=1;
                                    else{
                                         if (light[n.road-1].signal==1)
                                             brgflag[n.road-1]=1; 
                                         else
                                             n.y=temp;
                                      }
                          else if(temp< brgtop &&temp>brgbottom)
                             brgflag[n.road-1]=0;

        if (n.y > d.height||n.y<0) {
            n.y = 10*Math.random();
                                  carpermin[0].carnum=carpermin[0].carnum+1;
        }
                      }
    }
    repaint();
    }

    Node pick;
    double pickoldx, pickoldy;
    Image offscreen;
    Dimension offscreensize;
    Graphics offgraphics;

    final Color selectColor = Color.pink;
    final Color edgeColor = Color.black;
    final Color nodeColor = new Color(250, 220, 100);

    public void paintNode(Graphics g, Node n) {
    int x = (int)n.x;
    int y = (int)n.y;
    g.setColor((n==pick) ? selectColor : nodeColor); 
              int w= n.carW;                             
              int h=n.carL;
    g.fillRect(x - w/2, y - h / 2, w, h);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(x - w/2, y - h / 2, w-1, h-1);
              g.drawString(".", x-w/2+2, y+h/2-2);
    }

    public void paintRoad(Graphics g){
          Dimension d = size();
          g.setColor(Color.gray);
          for(int k=1; k<4; k++){
               g.drawLine(rdleft[k], 0, rdleft[k], rdbottom);
               g.drawLine(rdleft[k], rdtop, rdleft[k], d.height);
               g.drawLine(rdright[k], 0, rdright[k], rdbottom);
               g.drawLine(rdright[k], rdtop, rdright[k], d.height);
               g.drawLine(rdright[k-1], rdtop, rdleft[k], rdtop);
               g.drawLine(rdright[k-1], rdbottom, rdleft[k], rdbottom);
              }
          g.drawLine(rdright[3], rdbottom, d.width, rdbottom);
          g.drawLine(rdright[3], rdtop, d.width, rdtop);   
    }

public void paintLghtPeriod(Graphics g){
     Font warnFont, dispFont, stopFont;
     warnFont=new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
     dispFont=new Font("TimesRoman", 0, 12);
     stopFont=new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 14);
     Dimension d = size();

     offgraphics.setColor(Color.black);   
              if(lghtOrStp==1){
                 offgraphics.drawString("Traffic Light Period (1: red, 0: green)",  600,50);
                 offgraphics.setColor(Color.red);
                 offgraphics.drawString("red", 714, 50);
                 offgraphics.setColor(Color.green);
                 offgraphics.drawString("green", 747, 50);
                 offgraphics.setColor(Color.black);
                 for(int k=0; k<3; k++){ 
                   int tempred= light[k].redpauss/200, tempgreen= light[k].greenpauss/200;
                   int temp1=rdright[3]+170;    
                   int temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5;
                   if (light[k].signal==0){
                        temp2=temp1+tempred;
                        temp3=30*(k+1)+40;
                        temp4= temp2+tempgreen;
                        temp5=temp3+12;
                   }
                  else{
                        temp2=temp1+tempgreen;
                        temp3=30*(k+1)+40+12;
                        temp4= temp2+tempred;
                        temp5=temp3-12;
                 }
                 offgraphics.drawString("Light " +Integer.toString(k+1), temp1-40, (temp5+temp3)/2+5);
                 while (temp1<d.width){
                     offgraphics.drawLine(temp1, temp3, temp2, temp3);
           offgraphics.drawLine(temp2, temp5, temp4, temp5);
                     offgraphics.drawLine(temp1, temp3, temp1, temp5);
                     offgraphics.drawLine(temp2, temp3, temp2, temp5);
                     temp1=temp4;
                     temp2=temp1+tempred;
                     temp4=temp2+tempgreen;
                   }
                }
               offgraphics.setColor(Color.lightGray);
               offgraphics.fillRect(rdright[3]+328, 30, 15, 130);
               offgraphics.setColor(Color.gray);
               offgraphics.drawRect(rdright[3]+120, 20, 223, 145);
               offgraphics.setColor(Color.black);
               }
               else{
                 offgraphics.setFont(warnFont);
                 offgraphics.setColor(Color.white);
                 offgraphics.fillOval(rdleft[3]+175, rdtop-160, 70, 70);
                 offgraphics.setColor(Color.red);
                 offgraphics.fillOval(rdleft[3]+180, rdtop-155, 60, 60);
                 offgraphics.setColor(Color.white);
                 offgraphics.drawString("STOP", rdleft[3]+183, rdtop-116);
                 offgraphics.setColor(Color.black);
                 offgraphics.setFont(dispFont);
                 offgraphics.drawString("(California)", rdleft[3]+185, rdtop-50);
               }
}

public void paintLights(Graphics g){
        Font dispFont, stopFont;
        dispFont=new Font("TimesRoman", 0, 12);
        stopFont=new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 14);

        g.setFont(dispFont);
        int lightwidth=15;
        for(int k=1; k<4; k++){
           if(lghtOrStp==0){
             g.setColor(Color.red);
             g.fillOval(rdleft[k]-18, rdtop+4, lightwidth, lightwidth); 
             g.setColor(Color.white);
             g.setFont(stopFont);
             g.drawString("S", rdleft[k]-14, rdtop+16);
             g.setFont(dispFont);
           }
          else{ 
             g.setColor(Color.black);
             g.fillRect(rdleft[k]-18, rdtop+4, lightwidth-2, lightwidth-2); 
             g.setColor(light[k-1].signal==1 ? Color.red : Color.green);
             g.fillOval(rdleft[k]-7, rdtop+6, 6, 9); 
             g.setColor(light[k-1].signal==1 ? Color.green : Color.red);
             g.fillOval(rdleft[k]-16, rdtop+2, 9, 6); 
             g.setColor(Color.black);

             g.drawString("Light "+k, rdleft[k]-58, rdtop+17); 
           }
        }    
}

public void paintAxies(Graphics g){
              int temp1=610;
              int temp2=350;
              int temp3=temp1+160;
              int temp4= temp2-80;
              offgraphics.setColor(Color.gray);
              offgraphics.drawRect(rdright[3]+120, temp4-35, 220, 130);
              offgraphics.setColor(Color.black);
              offgraphics.drawLine(temp1, temp2, temp3, temp2);
              offgraphics.drawLine(temp3, temp2, temp3-10, temp2-2);
              offgraphics.drawLine(temp3, temp2, temp3-10, temp2+2);
              offgraphics.drawLine(temp1, temp2, temp1, temp4);
              offgraphics.drawLine(temp1, temp4, temp1-2, temp4+10);
              offgraphics.drawLine(temp1, temp4, temp1+2, temp4+10);
              for (int k=1; k<4; k++){
                int grid=20*k;
                offgraphics.drawLine(temp1, temp2- grid, temp1+5, temp2- grid);
                offgraphics.drawString(k+".0", temp1- 20, temp2- grid+5);
               }
              offgraphics.drawString("Time", temp3-10, temp2-10);
              offgraphics.drawString("Traffic Flow ", temp1-20, temp2-95);
              offgraphics.drawString("  (cars/sec.)", temp1-20, temp2-82);

              for (int k=0; k<40; k++){
                 if (k>=carpermin[0].count){
                        temp3=1;
                        offgraphics.setColor(Color.gray);
                     }
                 else{
                        temp3=2;
                        offgraphics.setColor(Color.black);
                   }
                 offgraphics.drawRect(k*3+temp1, temp2 - (int)(carpermin[0].carflow[k]*20+1), temp3, temp3);
                 }
   }

    public synchronized void update(Graphics g) {

    Dimension d = size();
    if ((offscreen == null) || (d.width != offscreensize.width) || (d.height != offscreensize.height)) {
        offscreen = createImage(d.width, d.height);
        offscreensize = d;
        offgraphics = offscreen.getGraphics();
    }

    offgraphics.setColor(getBackground());
    offgraphics.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
              paintRoad(offgraphics);
//draw lights
              paintLights(offgraphics);
//draw light period
              paintLghtPeriod(offgraphics);
//draw axies for the flow chart
             paintAxies(offgraphics);
//draw cars             
             for (int i = 0 ; i < nnodes ; i++) {
        paintNode(offgraphics, nodes[i]);
    }               
    g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public synchronized boolean mouseDown(Event evt, int x, int y) {
    double bestdist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nnodes ; i++) {
        Node n = nodes[i];
        double dist = (n.x - x) * (n.x - x) + (n.y - y) * (n.y - y);
        if (dist < bestdist) {
        pick = n;
                             pickoldx=n.x;
                             pickoldy=n.y;
        bestdist = dist;
        }
    }
    pick.x = x;
    pick.y = y;
    repaint();
    return true;
    }

    public synchronized boolean mouseDrag(Event evt, int x, int y) {
    pick.x = x;
    pick.y = y;
    repaint();
    return true;
    }

    public synchronized boolean mouseUp(Event evt, int x, int y) {
               boolean insidelane;
    pick.x = x;
    pick.y = y;
               insidelane=false;
    for (int k=1; k<4; k++)
                 if (x>rdleft[k]&&x<rdright[k])
                 {
                      pick.road=k;
                      pick.x=xpos[k-1];
                      pick.carW= carwidth;
                      pick.carL= carlength;
                      insidelane=true;
                  }
                 if (!insidelane&&(y<rdtop&&y>rdbottom))
                  {
                      pick.road=0;
                      pick.y=ypos;
                      pick.carW= carlength;
                      pick.carL= carwidth;

                     }
                  else if(!insidelane)
                   {
                     pick.x=pickoldx;
                     pick.y=pickoldy;
                     }
    pick = null;

    repaint();
    return true;
    }

    public void start() {
    relaxer = new Thread(this);
    relaxer.start();
    }
    public void stop() {
    relaxer.stop();
    }
}

public class Graph extends Applet {
    GraphPanel panel;
    int carnum;
    Thread LightThrd[] = new Thread[3];
    public void init() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel = new GraphPanel(this);
    add("Center", panel);

              carnum = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("carnum"));
              carnum=Math.min(carnum, 70);
              for (int k=0; k<carnum; k++)
                 panel.findNode(Integer.toString(k));
              panel.lghtOrStp=1;
              for (int k=0; k<3; k++){
                LightThrd[k] = new Thread(panel.light[k]);
                panel.light[k].redpauss=(k+1)*1000+3000;
                panel.light[k].greenpauss=panel.light[k].redpauss;
                LightThrd[k].start();
              }
              panel.carpermin[0].time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
              panel.carpermin[0].carnum=0;

             Panel btpnl=new Panel();
             add("South", btpnl);

             btpnl.add(new Button("Start"));
             btpnl.add(new Button("End"));

             btpnl.add(new Button("Stop Sign"));
             btpnl.add(new Button("Traffic Light"));
             btpnl.add(new Button("New Schedule for Lights"));
}

   public boolean action(Event evt, Object arg){
     if (((Button)evt.target).getLabel().equals("Traffic Light"))
       {
        if (panel.lghtOrStp==0){
          panel.lghtOrStp=1;
          for (int k=0; k<3; k++){
            LightThrd[k] = new Thread(panel.light[k]);
            panel.light[k].redpauss=(k+1)*1000+3000;
            panel.light[k].greenpauss=panel.light[k].redpauss;
            LightThrd[k].start();
            panel.carpermin[0].time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            panel.carpermin[0].carnum=0;
          }
         }
       }
     else if  (((Button)evt.target).getLabel().equals("Stop Sign"))
      {
         panel.lghtOrStp=0;
         for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
           if (LightThrd[k].isAlive())
              LightThrd[k].stop();
          }
         panel.carpermin[0].time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
         panel.carpermin[0].carnum=0;
       }
      else if  (((Button)evt.target).getLabel().equals("End"))
      {
           for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
             if (LightThrd[k].isAlive())
               LightThrd[k].stop();
          } 
           panel.stop();
        }
      else if  (((Button)evt.target).getLabel().equals("Start"))
      {
         if(panel.lghtOrStp==1)
           for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
            if (!LightThrd[k].isAlive()){
                 LightThrd[k] = new Thread(panel.light[k]);
                 LightThrd[k].start();
                }
          } 
         if (!panel.relaxer.isAlive())
            panel.start();
        }
     else if  (((Button)evt.target).getLabel().equals("New Schedule for Lights"))
      {
         if (panel.lghtOrStp==1){
           for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
             if (LightThrd[k].isAlive()){
                panel.light[k].redpauss=(int)(Math.random()*6000)+3000;
                panel.light[k].greenpauss=(int)(Math.random()*6000)+3000;
               }
            }
           panel.carpermin[0].time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
           panel.carpermin[0].carnum=0;
           panel.carpermin[0].carwt=0;

          }
        }
     return true;
    }
public void start() {
    panel.start();
}
    public void stop() {
    panel.stop();
    }
}
```

Please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: Which line is line 586? Also, you should know that just because your program compiles doesn't mean it works.

Comment: getParameter("carnum") does not return something that can be parsed to a Integer.

Comment: Java's exceptions are extremely helpful.  Get in the habit of looking at them.  The things to look for are "Number Format Exception" (Clearly means something is trying to parse a poorly formatted number). and the first thing in the stack trace that points to "Your" code then the line number at the end.  Go to that line and try to see what could be causing a "Number format exception"

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the line that is throwing the `NumberFormatException`.
`getParameter("carnum")` is probably null.

```
carnum = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("carnum"));
```

To find out try the following...

```
String tmpParam = getParameter("carnum");
if(tmpParam == null || tmpParam.length() == 0) {
    //Do some something to alert about error or throw exception.
    //throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter was null or empty.");
} else {
    carnum = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("carnum"));
}
```

Note that the following must also be defined in your HTML that loads the applet.

```
 <applet code="code" width=50 height=50>
     <param name=carnum value="3"> <---------------- Here
 </applet>
```